# Rails remove duplicate records from view conditional

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a books view where customer's have access to their most recent products.  I am trying to show current products and expired products.  All of this works well except for duplicate orders — I want to eliminate the dupes.

e.g. if current book title has same title as expired title don't show expired title, and if expired order has same title as expired order only show one title.

Here's my book index.

```
      <% if current_user_subscribed? %>
        <% @current_user.orders.map do |order| %>
          <% order.product.books.map do |book| %>   
            <% if order.created_at + order.expires.minutes > Time.now %>
              <%= link_to book.title, book %>

          # show book.title without dupes
            <% elsif order.product_id != order.product_id %> 
              <%= link_to book.title, book %>
            <% end %>
          <% end %>
        <% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds to me like a model concern, not a view concern.

```
# Model
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Class methods are allowed to be chained on ActiveRecord::Relation returned by order.books
  # @return [Array<Book>]
  def self.without_dups
    group_by(&:title).map do |title, books| 
      # Here I assume you simply want one book per title, with preference for the non-expired ones
      books.sort_by {|book| book.is_expired ? 0 : 1}.first
    end
  end
end

# Controller
class BooksController < ApplicationController
  def index
    # includes is used to avoid N+1 queries
    @orders = current_user.orders.includes(:books)
  end
end

# View
<% @orders.each do |order| %>
  <% order.books.without_dups.each do |book| %>
    ...
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

### Additional thoughts

Your original view code contains a lot of logic. It decides for itself what to render by calling methods directly on @current_user. It's better if the view focuses on **how** to render, while leaving the **what** to be rendered to the controller. That's why my controller sets up `@orders` and the view starts from there. Also, calling `#map` is unnecessary. You are not relying on the return value. It is not harmful, but `#each` is more natural in this case.

Comment: receiving `undefined method group_by for #<Class:0x007f9d69594238>`

Comment: what are you invoking `without_dups` on? can you paste the exact line here?

Comment: `<% order.product.books.without_dups.each do |book| %>`

Comment: What does `order.product.books` return? From the error it seems like it does not return an ActiveRecord relation. Are you sure `Order` has either `belongs_to :product` or `has_one :product` and `Product` has `has_many :books` defined on them? If `Order` has a `def self.product` or `Product` has a `def self.books` instead of using ActiveRecord associations, my suggestion above won't work.

Comment: If you do have all of them defined as ActiveRecord associations, can you try `to_a.group_by` instead of `group_by`?

Comment: It seems as though I do not have them.  I was able to filter the titles with `<% Book.select(:product_id).distinct.each do |o| %>`